# Open files in hex format same as Sublime Text 2

Tags: eclipse, hex-viewer, sublime-text

Is there a plugin for eclipse that will show me hex numbers when I open binary files the same way Sublime Text 2 does.

I checked `EHEP`, but it displays them in a weird table, but what I'm looking at a way to display them as sublime Text 2.

Like this

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Add the following to the preferences file:

```
"enable_hexadecimal_encoding": false
```

Comment: Is this added to Eclipse's preferences file or to Sublime's prefs file?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot showing what appears when you open a binary file after having enabled this setting? Thanks!